# OpenVPN LDAP plugin error

Tags: ldap, openvpn

I'm getting this error after (what I think is) a successful LDAP authentication:

```
No remote address supplied to OpenVPN LDAP Plugin (OPENVPN_PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT).
```

What does this error mean?

From syslog:

```
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1573 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1573 D:1450 EF:41 EB:4 ET:32 EL:0 ]
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '0ddbb6e3'
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '2c50bd2c'
Jan 28 13:57:58 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]184.151.61.191:58231, sid=7a0e31d7 42a199cf
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 VERIFY OK: depth=1, XXXXX
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 VERIFY OK: depth=0, XXXXX
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=0
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 TLS: Username/Password authentication succeeded for username 'ian.seyler' 
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1573', remote='link-mtu 1574'
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: 184.151.61.191:58231 [vpn.XXXXX.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]184.151.61.191:58231
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: No remote address supplied to OpenVPN LDAP Plugin (OPENVPN_PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT).
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT status=1
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_CLIENT_CONNECT failed with status 1: /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Jan 28 13:58:03 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 WARNING: client-connect plugin call failed
Jan 28 13:58:05 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Jan 28 13:58:05 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 Delayed exit in 5 seconds
Jan 28 13:58:05 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 SENT CONTROL [vpn.thalmic.com]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)
Jan 28 13:58:10 vmVPN ovpn-server[2774]: vpn.XXXXX.com/184.151.61.191:58231 SIGTERM[soft,delayed-exit] received, client-instance exiting
```

More details:

Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 x86-64

OpenVPN 2.2.1

Windows 2012 R2 AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN sets (or, rather, is supposed to set) the `ifconfig_pool_remote_ip` environment variable to the IP address assigned to the remote client. The error you're seeing is coming from the LDAP plugin failing to find this environment variable.

It's unclear to me why OpenVPN might not be setting this variable, but I'd suspect a bug in OpenVPN. That's a rather old version and, though I'm not finding any specific references to problems with setting that variable in the changelogs for newer versions, I'd consider trying a new version out.

Comment: Must have been a version issue. Upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 (OpenVPN 2.3.2) and the issue went away.